# How to remove special prices of products?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I am trying to update products prices with in a specific store. But when I do that, it shows me regular and special prices against each product. I want to set just one price against each product by disabling special price. How to do that? Here is my code.

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->load($prodId); 
    $prod->setPrice($newPrice)->getResource()->saveAttribute($prod, 'price');
    $prod->setSpecialPrice('')->getResource()->saveAttribute($prod, 'special_price');
    $prod->setSpecialFromDate('')->getResource()->saveAttribute($prod, 'special_from_date');
    $prod->setSpecialToDate('')->getResource()->saveAttribute($prod, 'special_to_date');
```

Comment: is your problem solved

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

It got the issue Actually `Price,Special Price,Special Price from date and  scope is Website`.So it was `taking  same for value for all stores`.As you was change it value for one store then it automatically change to other store.

[image]

**Solution:**

**1)** If you three store was in different Website then you can change  the those attribute
[image]

It works it  store would [image]  look like:

Full image link : http://oi60.tinypic.com/2j4vt6e.jpg

**2)** Delete those     `attribute and create new attribute of same name and proprity and but need Scope label store view`

Comment: Hi, I have tried it before. But result is same in both ways. It does not set my special prices to null. Any idea? Thank You

Comment: hi will check .. give some time

Comment: hi amit, its not a problem. I have separate website for each store.

Comment: I have asked a new question. please read.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44441/price-difference-between-category-view-page-and-product-view-page

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
$productIds = array($id1 , $id2); // specify your product ids here
$attributes = array( 
                'price' => $newPrice,
                'special_to_date' => '',
                'special_from_date => '',
                'special_price' => null); // attribute codes and values 

$storeId = $someStoreId // change this to your store id

Mage::getSingleton("catalog/product_action')
        ->updateAttributes($productIds , $attributes , $storeId); // update the products
```

Comment: Hi, I have different prices against each product. So in that scenario your code will work? If yes can you please elaborate your code.Thank You